# Conditional formatting using another cell that contains a keyword

Tags: excel, formatting, office365, conditional-formatting

I wish to create a conditional formatting rule such that the values in column D are bold if the cells in A contain the word `Total`. Below is an image of what I wish to achieve.

I understand how I can apply conditional formatting to a cell that contains specific text however how can I apply this rule such that it occurs if another cell contains this specific text. Since there is no "contains" function I'm unsure how to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Total",$A1))` - create a rule based on a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula in CF:

```
=RIGHT($A1,6)=" total"
```

apply to range `$A:$D`

[image]